# Iterate through columns in python and insert the columns names based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that is divided in ranges of number and lists, corresponding to those ranges. I'd like to iterate through each column, and get the max number, and put the header of the column in the right list according to the range. The lists and dataframe I have are:

```
       range                 A                 B                 C
0      0-300                20                 0               427   
1    300-500                66                16               341   
2    500-800               164                82               368   
3       >800              1245              1397               328 

low_group = [] # 0-300
mid1_group = [] # 300-500
mid2_group = [] # 500-800
high_group - [] # >800
```

The lists output should look like that:

```
low_group = ['C']
mid1_group = [] 
mid2_group = []
high_group - ['A','B']
```

Anybody knows how can I achieve that?

Comment: anything which you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `range` series as your index and use `idxmax`:

```
res = df.set_index('range').idxmax()

print(res)

A     >800
B     >800
C    0-300
dtype: object
```

Closer to your required format, you can use a dictionary mapping ranges to lists:

```
d = res.reset_index().groupby(0)['index'].apply(list).to_dict()

print(d)

{'0-300': ['C'], '>800': ['A', 'B']}
```

You can then rename keys as appropriate. In my opinion, it's good practice to avoid a variable number of variables. A dictionary is usually sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'd normally not use arbitrary named variables to store values. You may store it hashable getter object.

```
In [281]: mapper = {'0-300': 'low', '301-500': 'mid1', '501-800': 'mid2', '>800': 'high'}

In [282]: df.set_index('range').idxmax().map(mapper)
Out[282]:
A    high
B    high
C     low
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `melt`

```
df.melt('range').sort_values('value').drop_duplicates('variable',keep='last')
Out[487]: 
   range variable  value
8  0-300        C    427
3   >800        A   1245
7   >800        B   1397
```